# Importing plots from third party tools

Tags: pgfplots, plot, legend, octave

After working on some data in Octave, I need to export the resulting plots (made up of multiple curves and including axis labels and legends) and include them in a report.

My first choice (that I had read in [this paper](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-3/tb108veytsman.pdf)) was to print the figures with `print -depslatex -color "-Sxdim,ydim" "name.tex"` and then to import them into my Latex main file by using `\input{name.tex}`. However, the consequences of this solution are two, and none of them suite a proper document:

1. If I export the file with a "random" dimension, in order to fit in my document I have to import them by using `\resizebox{x\textwidth}{!}{\input{name.tex}}`. The plot fits in the space I want to, but the text results scaled and is barely readable.
2. If I manually look for the correct dimension that I need the plot to be in order to fit into the document, then the text in the legends flows out of the box and overlaps marks and axis ticks (I guess because only the text is exported as Latex and the legend box with its marks are considered part of the image).

At this point, I started looking for alternatives. I considered using Xmgr for plotting and PSTex to export the figures (at the bottom of [this page](http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Xmgr/doc/usage.html)), but I read that it has similar problems in dealing with legends because their size is not comprised in the output *.tex file and needs to be scaled manually.

Then I started reading the documentation of PGFplots, since I read that I could just import my figures generated through a third party software and add the legends directly in Latex inside a `tikzpicture` environment. However, page 253 of the manual reads that "The argument of `\legend` is a list of entries, one for each plot", implying that I cannot insert a legend with, say, three entries for a single imported plot (that is what I get from Octave).

All in all, I'm looking for a way to solve any one of these problems and I would really appreciate some help in this regard.

**EDIT:** As requested in a comment, here's a mwe showing the problems I mention.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, subcaption, pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{\input{plot1.tex}}
    \caption{Case 1: export from Octave with "random" dimensions.}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
    \input{plot2.tex}
    \caption{Case 1: export from Octave with correct dimensions.}
\end{subfigure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[legend entries={First curve, Second curve}]
    \addplot graphics [xmin=-4.4448, xmax=4.5728, ymin=-110, ymax=11.379]{plot3.png};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}`
```

The plots were exported from Octave with

1. `print -depslatex -color "-S600,400" "plot1.tex"`;
2. `print -depslatex -color "-S225,150" "plot2.tex"` while
3. the third one was simply saved through the GUI as a png image
   and produced this result:
   [image]

Comment: You can export in the `.eps` format, and use the `psfragx` package to replace the labels.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could edit your question and show us the graphs that you currently have created in Octave. Then we, the helpers, have it much easier to help you, because the room for "guessing" is much smaller.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Sorry, I was quite in a hurry yesterday and I thought the problem to be general enough to make do without the graphs.

Comment: @DavideM, thank you for editing the question. Now I think you are misinterpreting the manual. The sentence you quoted means, that each `\addplot` command *can have* (but must not necessarily) a legend entry (regardless of the source of the data that belong to that `\addplot` command.

Comment: For example add a legend to the example given at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355705 which is much more complicate than your use-case.

Comment: I can do that, but when I try to apply that to my situation (as shown now in the edited question) I can get only one entry in the legend, although I've inserted two. Any suggestion?

Comment: Of course, because you only have *one* `\addplot` command. The idea also was not to include a graphic, i.e. using `\addplot graphics` but to put your data points in an external file and plot it using `\addplot table`.

Comment: (As a side note you see that a wrong legend symbol is used, i.e. in addition there is a line to the dots. Said that it is pure luck that at least the color is right ...)

Comment: I know, but my point was to be able to draw the plot with an external tool and load it into my Latex document without much additional work. It was clear that if I drew it directly with pgfplots I wouldn't have any problem (apart from learning how to use it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the comments in the code on how to state legend symbols for an image included with `\addplot graphics` containing more than one line.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot [
            % state here the options you need to get a correct corresponding legend entry
            % (since this is the first `\addplot' command, the options belong to the 
            %  first legend entry)
            blue,
            mark=*,
            only marks,
        ] graphics [
            xmin=-4.4448,
            xmax=4.5728,
            ymin=-110,
            ymax=11.379,
        % used a dummy image, because you didn't provide the original one
        ] {example-image};

        % now state with the following command all the other legend symbols
        \addlegendimage{
            red,
            only marks,
        }

        \legend{
            first,
            second,
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]